# Error on using Primefaces Push with Tomcat 7.

Tags: primefaces, tomcat7, atmosphere

I am trying to implement the basic counter example given in the primefaces showcase. When I run the application on Eclipse, the counter seems to get incremented after every click. But on Firefox and Google Chrome, the incremented value is shown only after refresh (which is not push). 
I also get an error like
**org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Failed using comet support: org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7AsyncSupportWithWebSocket, error: Tomcat failed to detect this is a Comet application because context.xml is missing or the Http11NioProtocol Connector is not enabled.**

What does context.xml do? What should it contain?

Answer (score 1):

you should change your connector protocol like this in your server.xml :

```
  <Service name="Catalina">
  <!--    
    <Connector port="8080" address="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ..../>
  -->
  <!-- 
    HTTP 1.1 protocol is replaced with org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol 
  -->
  <Connector port="8080" address="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" />
  ...
  </Service>
```